# AWK: print ALL rows with MAX value in one field Per the other field including Identical Rows with Max value

Tags: awk, duplicates, max, field

I am trying to keep the rows with highest value in column 2 per column 1 including identical rows with max value like the desired output below.

Data is

```
a   55
a   66
a   130
b   88
b   99
b   99
c   110
c   130
c   130
```

Desired output is

```
a   130
b   99
b   99
c   130
c   130
```

I could find great answers from this site, but not exactly for the current question.

```
awk '{ max=(max>$2?max:$2); arr[$2]=(arr[$2]?arr[$2] ORS:"")$0 } END{ print arr[max] }' file
```

yields the output which includes the identical rows But max value is from all rows not per column 1.

```
a       130
c       130
c       130
```

```
awk '$2>max[$1] {max[$1]=$2 ; row[$1]=$0} END{for (i in row) print row[i]}' file
```

Output includes the max value per column 1 but NOT include identical rows with max values.

```
a       130
b       99
c       130
```

Would you please help me to trim the data in desired way. Even all codes above are obtained from your questions and answers in this site. Appreciate that!! Many thanks for helps in advance!!!

Comment: Add a counter for every duplicate entry then print an entry counter times.

Comment: @konsolebox I guess you meant the way Andre provided below. Appreciate that!

Answer (score 3):

I've used this approach in the past:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if($2 > max[$1]){max[$1]=$2}; next} max[$1] == $2' test.txt test.txt
a   130
b   99
b   99
c   130
c   130
```

This requires you to pass in the same file twice (i.e. awk '...' test.txt test.txt), so it's not ideal, but hopefully it provides the required output with your actual data.

Comment: Next intuively should be in outer block and second line can be simplified to `max[$1] == 2`.

Comment: You are absolutely right - thank you for the correction - I adapted this answer from a more complicated script. I'll edit the answer now. Thanks @konsolebox

Comment: @jared_mamrot Sincerely appreciate that it works perfectly for my needs and was impressive for prompt answer and edition to follow-up comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Using any awk:

```
awk '
    { cnt[$1,$2]++; max[$1]=$2 }
    END { for (key in max) { val=max[key]; for (i=1; i<=cnt[key,val]; i++) print key, val } }
' file
a 130
b 99
b 99
c 130
c 130
```

Comment: This assumes that `file` is sorted by ascending values by key. Fixable with `max[$1]=max[$1] < $2 ? $2 : max[$1]` or presorting...

Comment: @dawg, right, as per the sample input. If not then `sort file | awk ...` or tweak as you say.

Comment: " sort file | awk ' { cnt[$1,$2]++; max[$1]=$2 } END { for (key in max) { val=max[key]; for (i=1; i<=cnt[key,val]; i++) print key, val } } ' " works perfectly for my unsorted data! When there are additional columns not involved in functions, how should I modify to print all columns? Thanks much!!!

Comment: @SWK ask a new question about that as this is a good solution to the question you asked here but it's not the right starting point for the question in your comment. You're welcome.

Comment: @dawg if you meant the modification like this '' awk '{ cnt[$1,$2]++; max[$1]=max[$1] < $2 ? $2 : max[$1] } END { for (key in max) { val=max[key]; for (i=1; i<=cnt[key,val]; i++) print key, val } }' file " , still needed sorted file. I may be wrong. Thanks!!!

Comment: @SWK: With Ed's unmodified script, the line `max[$1]=$2` is not the `max` unless the max is also the last one seen in the file. With `max[$1]=max[$1] < $2 ? $2 : max[$1]` it is a true max.

Comment: I just put a new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75403832/awk-print-all-rows-with-max-value-in-one-field-per-the-other-field-including-id. Thanks Ed!

Comment: @dawg I should be careful then when I use max[$1]=$2 ! Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `awk`. The second loop should be light, just repeating the duplicated max values.

```
% awk 'arr[$1] < $2{arr[$1] = $2;                       # get max value
         co[$1]++; if(co[$1] == 1){x++; id[x] = $1}}    # count unique ids
       arr[$1] == $2{n[$1,arr[$1]]++}                   # count repeated max
       END{for(i=1; i<=x; i++){
             for(j=1; j<=n[id[i],arr[id[i]]]; j++){print id[i], arr[id[i]]}}}' file
a 130
b 99
b 99
c 130
c 130
```

or, if order doesn't matter

```
% awk 'arr[$1] < $2{arr[$1] = $2}
       arr[$1] == $2{n[$1,arr[$1]]++}
       END{for(i in arr){
             j=0; do{print i, arr[i]; j++} while(j < n[i,arr[i]])}}' file
c 130
c 130
b 99
b 99
a 130
```

-- EDIT --

Printing data in additional columns

```
% awk 'arr[$1] < $2{arr[$1] = $2}
       arr[$1] == $2{n[$1,arr[$1]]++; line[$1,arr[$1],n[$1,arr[$1]]] = $0}
       END{for(i in arr){
             j=0; do{j++; print line[i,arr[i],j]} while(j < n[i,arr[i]])}}' file
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
a   130 data3
```

##### Data

```
% cat file
a   55  data1
a   66  data2
a   130 data3
b   88  data4
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   110 data7
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

Comment: Thanks much for your help! it works for me. When data has multiple columns, how should the print option be modified to print all columns for those rows? Thanks!

Comment: @SWK I added an edit to get additional columns!

Comment: It works perfect for my needs and I thank you for your prompt response, too!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a ruby to do that:

```
ruby -e '
grps=$<.read.split(/\R/).
    group_by{|line| line[/^\S+/]}
# {"a"=>["a   55", "a   66", "a   130"], "b"=>["b   88", "b   99", "b   99"], "c"=>["c   110", "c   130", "c   130"]}

maxes=grps.map{|k,v| v.max_by{|s| s.split[-1].to_f}}
# ["a   130", "b   99", "c   130"]

grps.values.flatten.each{|s| puts s if maxes.include?(s)}
' file
```

Prints:

```
a   130
b   99
b   99
c   130
c   130
```

Comment: I may look for the solutions using ruby in the future and thank you for your code and explanations.