# AWK: print ALL rows with MAX value in one field Per the other field including Identical Rows with Max value AND multiple columns

Tags: arrays, awk

I appreciate that I was touched with many solutions promptly from many contributors!!! ([AWK: print ALL rows with MAX value in one field Per the other field including Identical Rows with Max value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75392860/awk-print-all-rows-with-max-value-in-one-field-per-the-other-field-including-id/75401868#75401868))

This question include data with one more column and I'd like to keep the rows with highest value in column 2 per column 1 including identical rows with max value from the data containing multiple columns, and print all columns.

Data

```
a   130 data1
a   55  data2
a   66  data3
b   88  data4
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   110 data7
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

Desired output

```
a   130 data1
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

Code from @jared_mamrot **works perfectly and print out all columns.**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{if($2 > max[$1]){max[$1]=$2}; next} max[$1] == $2' file file
```

Code @Andre Wildberg provided also **works perfectly and print out all columns**.

```
awk 'arr[$1] < $2{arr[$1] = $2}
       arr[$1] == $2{n[$1,arr[$1]]++; line[$1,arr[$1],n[$1,arr[$1]]] = $0}
       END{for(i in arr){
             j=0; do{j++; print line[i,arr[i],j]} while(j < n[i,arr[i]])}}' file
```

The awk script below by @Ed Morton also **works perfectly for my previous data with 2 columns**. It prints two columns; key and val.

**My further question is when I have multiple columns in data, how should I modify this script to print all columns.**

```
sort file | awk '
    { cnt[$1,$2]++; max[$1]=$2 }
    END { for (key in max) { val=max[key]; for (i=1; i<=cnt[key,val]; i++) print key, val } }
'
```

Thank you all for great helps!!!

Answer (score 4):

Using any awk and sort:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr file | awk '!seen[$1]++{max=$2} $2==max'
a   130 data1
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

or:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr file | awk '$1!=prev{prev=$1; max=$2} $2==max'
a   130 data1
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

original script before realising I'd over-thought it:

```
$ sort -k1,1 -k2,2nr file | awk '!seen[$1]++{key=$1; max=$2} $1==key && $2==max'
a   130 data1
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

The value of `seen[$1]++` is 0 the first time any given value of $1 appears in the input, and some incremental non-zero number when that same $1 appears again. So, the value of `!seen[$1]++` is `1` (i.e. `true` in a conditional context) the first time a given `$` is seen in the input, and `0` (`false`) afterwards. So, the first time `a` appears as `$1` we set `key` to `a` and `max` to whatever value $2 has, i.e. `130` in this case. That's it for the involvement of `!seen["a"]++`.

From then on we just print every line for which $1 is `a` and $2 is `130`, which in this case is just the first line of input.

Then the same happens when `b` is first seen as $1.

Comment: Wow! I won't generate new question^^ but while syntax includes only $1 and $2, how does '!seen[$1]++' not exclude 3rd or 5th line? and how 'seen[$1]++' would keep still all line after first seen $1? Thanks again!

Comment: @SWK I added an explanation, let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks much for being thorough!!! Now I see the actual function of seen[$1]++ and !seen[$1]++, and {key=$1; max=$2} does kind of setting $2 per $1 (actually both way). Thus even $2==max implies $1==key && $2==max here. I really appreciate that I saved at least few months to learn this much thanks to you all contributors!!

Comment: @SWK you mentioning `even $2==max implies $1==key && $2==max here` made me realize I didn't need to save or test `key` at all if I'm using `seen[]` and also I didn't even really need that array of the $1 values, just the previous one read. I updated the script.

Answer (score 3):

You just need one additional associative array to store 3rd column as value and key as first 2 columns and a running counter being computer in `cnt` variable:

```bash
awk '{
   map[$1,$2,++cnt[$1,$2]] = $0
   max[$1] = ($2 > max[$1] ? $2 : max[$1])
}
END {
   for (key in max) {
      val = max[key]
      for (i=1; i<=cnt[key,val]; i++)
         print map[key,val,i]
   }
}' file

a   130 data1
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

There is no need to sort the file for this `awk` solution.

Comment: I finally might fully understand max[$1]=($2 > max[$1] ? $2 : max[$1]) to skip sort. Thanks!!!

Comment: @SWK: I have made an update to handle any number of fields in input not just 3 fields.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there may be more than 3 fields to a row:

```
$ cat file
a   130 data1
a   55  data2
a   66  data3
b   88  data4
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   110 data7
c   130 data8
c   130 data9 data10 data11
```

One idea for modifying the current `awk` code:

```
awk '
    { key=$1; val=$2                    # save 1st two fields
      $1=$2=""                          # clear 1st two fields
      gsub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")          # remove leading white space from line

      ++cnt[key,val]
      max[key]=(val > max[key] ? val : max[key])
      row[key,val,cnt[key,val]]=$0      # save rest of line
    }
END { for (key in max) { 
          val=max[key]
          for (i=1; i<=cnt[key,val]; i++) 
              print key, val, row[key,val,i]
      }
    }
'  file
```

This generates:

```
a 66 data3
b 99 data5
b 99 data6
c 130 data8
c 130 data9 data10 data11
```

Comment: I was about to ask to @anubhava for more than 3 fields. Thank you for additional explanation too!!

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
    $1 != firstcol{ firstcol=$1; max=$2; map[NR]=$0 } 
    $1 == firstcol{
        if($2>max){ map[NR--]=$0; max=$2 }
        if($2==max) map[NR]=$0
    }
    END{
        for(i in map) print map[i]
    }
' inputfile

a   130 data1
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

Answer (score 1):

The same ruby works with minor adjustments:

```
ruby -e '
grps=$<.read.split(/\R/).
    group_by{|line| line[/^\S+/]}
# {"a"=>["a   130 data1", "a   55  data2", "a   66  data3"], "b"=>["b   88  data4", "b   99  data5", "b   99  data6"], "c"=>["c   110 data7", "c   130 data8", "c   130 data9"]}

maxes=grps.map{|k,v| v.max_by{|s| s.split[1].to_f}}.map{|s| s.split[0..1] }
# [["a", "130"], ["b", "99"], ["c", "130"]]

grps.values.flatten.each{|s| puts s if maxes.include?(s.split[0..1])}
' file
```

Prints:

```
a   130 data1
b   99  data5
b   99  data6
c   130 data8
c   130 data9
```

Once you start getting into 3 or more columns to manage, it is easier to use ruby (or Perl, Python, etc) because of the support for slicing, grouping and joining arrays.